# Update a record with nested objects giving duplicate key error

Tags: mysql, go, crud, go-gorm

I need to update a user profile, I'm taking the whole profile, allowing the user to edit what he wants then send the whole profile again to the server to save whatever values updated, but it didn't work.

```golang
User {
   Address {
       Country {
             // fields
        },
    // fields
   },

  Settings { 
    // fields
   },

  username: string, 
  email: string,
}
```

to avoid complications, I want to send the whole record, save it all, update whatever updated or save the old values again for the fields that did not update.

I tried this:

```golang
// Update User data
func (r *RepositoryUserCrud) Update(uid int, user models.User) (int, error) {
    var err error

// 1, did not work, getting  Error 1062: Duplicate entry for email
 err = r.db.Debug().Model(&models.User{}).Where("id = ?", unit(uid)).Updates(user).Error

// 2, did not work, getting  Error 1062: Duplicate entry for email
 err = r.db.Save(&user).Error;

// 3, I tried to skip the duplicate key error by using {onConflict: DoNothing}
err = r.db.Debug().Clauses(r.db.Model(&models.User{})
                  .Where("id = ?", uint(uid)))
                  .OnConflict{DoNothing: true}
                  .Updates(user)
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

In case the change has happend in the deeply nested objects, how to apply the changes to their tables? or should I do this manually?

Comment: Why did you tag all your go code snippets as `js`??

Comment: it giving  Error 1062: Duplicate entry for email, like trying to enter a new record not update the existing

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to update the email to one that already exists in your table. And make sure every sub entity you are updating has an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the email field is primary key, and I'm not passing the ID as part of the updated record, so it's basically trying to create a new record with the same email.

so this code worked, but make sure to provide the `ID` with the record itself.

```
err = r.db.Debug().Model(&models.User{}).Where("id = ?", unit(uid)).Updates(user).Error
```

I also needed to update the linked rows from other tables manually.